# Full background Image size in browser in any resolution

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am trying  to create a full `background` website. Now i am working with `1920*1080 resolution` screen. But i have to fit the background in any resolution. I use the following css

```
html {
    background:#65b5cc url(webbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
    }
```

But this is not re-size the background when browser re-size, and one more doubt is i use the background as `jpg` image size is 1627*768 . is that the right size. I want to show vector type drawings as my background, so want to get maximum quality in less size. Guide me.

Thanks

Comment: try
background-size: 100%;

Comment: thank you its working.. can you tell the prefect background image size(jpg image size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this property "background-size:100%"
```

Comment: can you tell the prefect background image size(jpg image size)

Comment: Use image size max 1920 X 800px. For all resolutions that will perform perfectly in body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    background: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100/) no-repeat center center fixed #65b5cc;
    // Make sure your SVG image expands to the whole window/page.
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

If you use an SVG image, its actual dimensions doesn't matter since it's a vector file, so it can scale to any size without loosing quality.

[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e7jzevss/)

Comment: :can you tell the prefect background image size(jpg image size)

Comment: Perfect for what? If block dimensions are 200x200 pixels, so perfect will be image with resolutions 200x200 pixels.

Comment: For non-vector images the bigger the image the better in terms of resolution/quality. But that comes at the expense of performance: bigger file size.
Use a SVG file if possible otherwise use the average dimensions of your target audience screen size.